# Github API to get the author/committer of specific line of code

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using Github code search API to get search for some text in a given repository. The response doesn't seem to contain any information related to the content that matched, sha/hash of the commit or the author/committer info:

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+repo:jquery/jquery
```

Is there any way to get the author/committer of the given line of code in a repo using the Github API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For searching commits we can use the new Commit Search API which is currently available for developers for preview . During the preview period we need to explicitly specify a custom media type in the 'Accept' header. For example your search using this API could be - `curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview' \https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=addClass+repo:jquery/jquery`
. ref: [Search Commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits)

Comment: Yes, I did already attempt to use Commit Search API but that requires commit/revision. I was more interested in going from search to author. Thanks!